# XtraReport - How to preview one page but print/export all pages?

Tags: asp.net, performance, devexpress, xtrareport

I'm running into a performance issue with XtraReports.  Is there a way to limit the amount of data shown on the preview (in the ReportViewer control), but when the user goes to export/print give them all the data?  I've tried to filter the dataset by just taking the top 10 rows for the preview and that works, but not sure how to remove the filter when the user goes to print/export.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can limit amout of data in preview and still get all data in export, but you can improve performance of your reports. I'm using XtraReports together with [DevExpress XPO](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/ORM/) and it seems that report fetches all data during initial rendering of report, when you browse through pages and during export. If you want your report to fetch data only on initial report rendering use [report caching](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1946.aspx). Caching, together with reasonable fetched data limit did it for me.
Also, if you want to limit report printed record count you can use [ReportPrintOptions.DetailCount](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraReports/DevExpressXtraReportsUIReportPrintOptions_DetailCounttopic).

Answer (score -1):

you should use

```
using DevExpress.XtraPrinting;
using DevExpress.XtraReports.UI;
using DevExpress.XtraPrinting.Preview;
```

in button pf print use

```
 XtraReport1 prt = new XtraReport1();
    prt.ShowPreview();
```

Comment: And how exactly would this method 'Preview' a ready made report?